# How to programmatically open xyz program while user try to open any work(.doc) file?

Tags: java, c, .net, ms-word, ms-office

How could I `programmatically` open `xyz program` **whenever** I go for open specific **word**(**.doc or .docx**) `file` ?

**For example,**
I am creating 1-`screen`(assume `desktop application`) where I will first ask 2-things from user,

step - 1. any word(.doc or .docx) file which is location inside user's system.

step - 2. target program(for example, any one `audio file`). Here I would like to add that it can be any thing. it can be `.mp3`, `.mp4`, `.exe`.

> So that finally what will happen like whenever user will try  to
>   open(step-1) a particular word file at that time, specified audio
>   file(step-2) will automatically open & play a nice song once.

*how will I achieve this using programmatically (first priority will goes to java language) ?*

*Any help will really appreciate!!*

**UPDATE -**
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T5Dw_GGeZFS6HUFOY2mYe2G79qkxXhz2/view?usp=sharing (please refer this link in order to understand my clear requirement & see what best you can do).

Comment: "problematically" ==> "programmatically" ?

Comment: Very unclear what you want, you say ”problematically”, you want it to fail?

Comment: What is the point of sending a Word document to a media player? Or does the source file contain a play list?

Comment: Since you're most likely playing within the Windows operating system almost all files have an association with the or an application that is designed to run those particular files. With this in mind you can use  `Desktop.getDesktop().open(yourpathAndFileName);`. Otherwise use ProcessBuilder.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thanks for notify me. I have correct myself.

Comment: @DevilsHnd Yes, I am interested with this solution in windows os. could you give any hint more in detail. might be some article or link I can read & learn from there ?

Comment: @vishalgajera - Provided an answer to your question. :)

Comment: @vishalgajera - Sorry...In no way does that video tell or show me what you are trying to accomplish but I'm going to take a guess at it: You want to create an application that, when you select (double-click) a file from Windows Explorer you want to open that file with its associated application and you want expand that association to also open the file you have associated with it in your application.

Comment: Use VBA in the Word document.

Comment: You can use a Word compatible program, example `"my_word_program.exe"`, to open `"file.doc"`. But you want to use `"file.mp3"` to open `"file.doc"`. That makes no sense. Also why do you tag both C and Java? There is a solution to run executables in C with `CreateProcess`, it needs `"windows.h"` header file. I assume there is also a Java solution.

Comment: How is this .Net?

Comment: @PepitoSh, I thought, it's Microsoft product so might be possible to handle such kind of things through .Net. that's why .Net tag has been added.